# how can I force to visit my site by 80 port?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I created one website on Firebase, now I want to move the website out from firebase. On the new hosting server, the website url keeps visiting 443 port.

How can I force the port change? Is there any cached on the web browser I need clean them up maybe? I want to make it 80 port by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Hosting will only serve traffic over HTTPS, so port 443.

There is no way to force traffic to be served over non-secured HTTP. But traffic coming in to port 80 will (or at least *should*) automatically get redirected to port 443 with a 307 response.

From a quick test request I just did:

> Request URL:http://trenches.firebaseapp.com/
>
> Request Method:GET

Response

> Status Code:307 Internal Redirect
>
> Location:https://trenches.firebaseapp.com/
>
> Non-Authoritative-Reason:HSTS

Comment: Firebase has very poor support for the region in China :(

Answer (score 0):

Your new host probably has SSL configured for your site (https). Disable SSL to revert to port 80 (http).

Comment: That would apply to most hosts, but Firebase Hosting will only serve traffic over HTTPS (so port 443).