# Domain can only be accessed through secure

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I've registered my domain with name-cheap and hosted it with firebase, i'm trying to access the domain I've registered as www.comfortercoins.com is only accessible through secure https:// when i try to access it via http:// it doesn't work, site is not reachable. what could be the problem?

Comment: Firebase Hosting will only server your traffic over HTTPS. Requests on port 80 will be redirected. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732982/how-can-i-force-to-visit-my-site-by-80-port/38733674#38733674

Answer (score 2):

Firebase automatically provides an SSL certificate for any site hosted on their service. It is intended to provide a secure connection.

Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#wait-for-ssl-certificate-provisioning).

Quote from the provided link:

> Firebase Hosting provisions an SSL certificate for your domain and serves your content over a global CDN.